# React.js : use <span> to submit the <form> inside render() method

Tags: html, forms, reactjs

Good day everyone.

I have a form and a table inside the render() method of .jsx Component.
And I need to use one of span inside the table to submit the form and pass the action to SpringMVC RestController.

There is some confines:

1) Unfotrunately I can't use Submit or Button input types in this specific happening.

2) Also I can't use JQuery.

The Component code

```html
export default class MyClass extends Component {
  
  render() {
    let rootUrl = '../rest';
    
    return (
      
        <form action={rootUrl + "/books/genres/genre"} method="get" name="bookForm" id="bookForm">
        <table className="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-5">
          <tbody>
              <td className="vertical-align-middle"><small>Book Title</small></td>
              <td className="vertical-align-middle"><small>Author</small></td>
              <td className="vertical-align-middle"><small>Year</small></td>
              <!-- This span must submit the form -->
                  <td className="vertical-align-middle"><span className="link-style" >Submit</span></td>
                  </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'll be very grateful for hint how to realize it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set an `onClick` handler for your `span`:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(super){
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(evt){
    //submit your form
  }

  render() {
    //rest of your code
   <td className="vertical-align-middle">
     <span className="link-style" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</span>
   </td>
  }
}
```